# New column as sum of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
               Date       Par1       Par2       Par3       Par4       Par5       Par6
01.01.1980  0:00:00    1.52629    1.23292    0.17391   -0.01693    0.01112    0.04812    0.03623
01.01.1980  1:00:00    1.52653    1.23290    0.17350   -0.01706    0.01105    0.04810    0.03622
01.01.1980  2:00:00    1.52678    1.23287    0.17309   -0.01720    0.01097    0.04807    0.03621
01.01.1980  3:00:00    1.52702    1.23285    0.17268   -0.01733    0.01090    0.04805    0.03621
01.01.1980  4:00:00    1.52726    1.23282    0.17228   -0.01747    0.01082    0.04803    0.03620
01.01.1980  5:00:00    1.52751    1.23280    0.17187   -0.01760    0.01075    0.04800    0.03619
```

I never know in advance how many columns there will be in this table.

How do I create a new column that is the sum of all the others (except date and time, of course)?

I have read about many ways to do this. But they all describe a situation when the number of columns is known in advance.

For example:

```
df['z'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.x + row.y, axis=1)
```

or

```
df['z'] = df.x + df.y
```

Thank you for your advices!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Date     Par1     Par2     Par3     Par4     Par5     Par6     Par7      sum
0  01.01.1980  1.52629  1.23292  0.17391 -0.01693  0.01112  0.04812  0.03623  3.01166
1  01.01.1980  1.52653  1.23290  0.17350 -0.01706  0.01105  0.04810  0.03622  3.01124
2  01.01.1980  1.52678  1.23287  0.17309 -0.01720  0.01097  0.04807  0.03621  3.01079
3  01.01.1980  1.52702  1.23285  0.17268 -0.01733  0.01090  0.04805  0.03621  3.01038
4  01.01.1980  1.52726  1.23282  0.17228 -0.01747  0.01082  0.04803  0.03620  3.00994
5  01.01.1980  1.52751  1.23280  0.17187 -0.01760  0.01075  0.04800  0.03619  3.00952
```

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a list of columns to be excluded. Then, you can add up all other columns in the df.

```py
excluded_columns = {'tot'}
df['total'] = sum([df[x] for x in df.columns.values if x not in excluded_columns])
```